# How to save the file to user working directory when building R package?

Tags: r, r-package

I am learning to build R packages (`myPkg`) and have a function that will save a `rds` file to working directory like that:

```
myPkg_fun <- (path = ".") {
  str <- "Hello World"
  out_path <- file.path(path, "str.rds")
  saveRDS(str, out_path)
}
```

I can install and load my package `library(myPkg)` in another project using RStudio, but I cannot save the `.rds` to my (user) working directory.

When I use `myPkg::myPkg_fun(path=".")`, the `.rds` is actually saved in `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/myPkg/examples/`. I think there are some missing steps to connect the package path to user's working directory.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Nope, there’s no missing step: the code that you’ve shown works as expected, and will use the *current working directory*. This generally shouldn’t be inside the package library, unless that happens to be your current working directory. — Are you maybe calling the function during the package installation?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for the response. I called the function after the installation completed and I also tried to restart the RStudio, but negative :(

Comment: What does `getwd()` return when you enter it into the terminal *before* doing your `myPkg::myPkg_fun(path=".")`? As Konrad said, there is nothing else required here. You are saving the file into the *local* folder; it seems that your local folder was "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/myPkg/examples/".

Comment: @MauritsEvers `getwd()` return my local folder in the function, instead of package library. But if I add `print(getwd())` in the package and re-install, it shows library path, `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/myPkg/examples/`. That's why I am so confused ~

Comment: Where exactly did you put `print(getwd())`? Did you put it in the function body? In a new R session, when you run `getwd()`, what do you get? Have you used the R debugger before? Try running `debugonce(myPkg::myPkg_fun)` and then calling your function. Checking the value of `getwd()` at each step. It should not be changing but if it does you can see where it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not making the question clear enough. The pkg I am building is a shiny library. I figured out the reason that is because `myPkg_fun()` is run in an shiny app and by default, the working dir is where the `app.R` locates.

The solution is to

1. set user's working dir in the env variable
2. read the env variable and force to reset the working dir to the user's working dir in the app

So that the `.rds`  can be saved into the right folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's incredibly easy to create new packages in R (thanks to RStudio and packages such as `devtools` and `usethis`), I've created a [minimal package](https://github.com/mevers/myPkg) with the single function `myPkg_fun()`.

I suggest

1. Taking a look at the GitHub repo to see what's in the package and how it's set up compared to your local package.
2. Installing the package with `remotes::install_github("mevers/myPkg")`.
3. Opening a fresh R terminal (or start a fresh RStudio instance, making sure that no project is open) and navigate to a specific working folder. Make sure you either `setwd()` or "More > Set As Working Directory" in the RStudio file browser window.
4. Do `library(myPkg); myPkg_fun()` and observe how the RDS file is saved in your local working folder.